# JNDI lookup JBoss Application Server 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

How can I access remote EJB in Jboss AS 7? When I deploy application on Jboss AS 7 , I can see portable jndi names but unable to access using same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with latest release of JBoss 7.1

Answer (score 5):

Will be implemented in JBoss AS 7.1: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1338

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your ejb module has the same class loader with the module which needs the access of EJB.
and then, use these code

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
ic.lookup(*the jndi name you see*);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work if you start as -server-config standalone-preview.xml ?

Since this turns on the rest of the JavaEE6 (not certified though). I'm talking about the  Jboss 7.0.2 (Everything).

Good luck!